# Android shape xml adding a circle to square

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-xml, android

I am having trouble figuring out how to add a circle to a square shape in xml.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#E68C7C"/>
<padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
```

I am setting the above xml as the background to a textview. That part works fine. I am trying to draw a circle in the bottom right corner of the the square as shown below.

[image: circle button bottom right]

Comment: Try using the `layer-list` options and creating two layers one of which is a rectangle while the other is a `android:shape ="oval"` and set params to the second shape to give it the red color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146795/android-how-can-i-use-the-layer-list-and-shape-elements-to-draw-a-horizontal-ru

Comment: How do I go about making the circle be in the bottom right corner? What I'm getting is a square with a slightly smaller circle in it.

Comment: You can try offsetting with `<item top:##px left:...>`, etc as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), but you'll probably have issues with scaling. Honestly, this looks like it would be roughly 98.3% easier with a 9patch background.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="20dp"
        android:right="20dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#E68C7C" />
            <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
            <size android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="90dp"
        android:top="90dp"
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:right="15dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size android:width="2dp"
                android:height="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The output of above code is:

[image]

I hope its work for you.